# \\u0000 cannot be converted to text error

Tags: javascript, postgresql, next.js, supabase

I am using NextJS and supabase to insert some data into PostgreSQL database. Data is array of objects. The error is like this `\\u0000 cannot be converted to text. unsupported Unicode escape sequence`. There is no unicode character like `\\u0000` in my data.

There is a error response but I cant see which keys value is causing the error. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

```js
const Data = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.from('db').insert([])  
      return res.status(200).json({
        data: data,
        error: error,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: u000 is the Unicode representation of `Null`. [The Unicode Standad](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf)

Comment: Hi @rojass ! Do you have the actual code with some data you used to insert data?